# Update state in setInterval via dispatch outside component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, dispatch

I currently have a functional component Form that triggers a task to occur. Once the submission is complete, I create a setInterval poll to poll for the status of the task. The code roughly looks like

```
export function Form(props: FormProps) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const pollTaskStatus = () => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(async() => {
      const response = await fetchTaskStatus() // Function in different file
      if (response.status === 'COMPLETE') {
        dispatch(Actions.displayTaskComplete())
        clearInterval(intervalId)
      }
    })
  }
  
  const submitForm = async() => {
    await onSubmitForm() // Function in different file
    pollTaskStatus()
  }

  return (
    ...
    <button onClick={submitForm}>Submit</button>
  )
}
```

When the action is dispatched, the redux store is supposed to be updated and a component is supposed to update alongside it showing a message that the task is complete. However, I see the action logged with an updated store state but nothing occurs. If I just try to dispatch the same action with useEffect() wrapped around it outside the submitForm functions, the message appears. I've searched online and people say that you need to wrap useEffect around setInterval but I can't do that because the function that calls setInterval is not a custom hook or component. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to answer your question without seeing all the code.

But my guts feeling is that this might no have anything to do with *React*.

```
  const pollTaskStatus = () => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(async() => {
      console.log('fire to fetch')
      const response = await fetchTaskStatus() // Function in different file
      if (response.status === 'COMPLETE') {
        console.log('success from fetch')
        dispatch(Actions.displayTaskComplete())
      }
    })
  }
```

Let's add two console lines to your code. What we want to see is to answer the following questions.

- is the `setInterval` called in every 500ms?
- is any of the call finished as success?
- how many dispatch has been fired after submission

If you can answer all these questions, most likely you can figure out what went wrong.

Comment: hey, I've pasted the logs and I see both logs fire. The interval is being set & called initially and there is a final call being done just before the dispatch. I've thought about it again shortly after posting this and realized I could probably just trigger this same functionality with a workaround. I created a variable to hold a boolean saying the form was submitted and a useEffect() with that boolean as a dependency. when the value of the boolean changes, it kicks off the poll. Not great, but works when conforming with React.